# is $x\cdot y=\sum_{i}^{n}{x_{i}y_{i}}$ the same as $x^Ty$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading the book Fundamentals of Error-Correcting Codes and on page 5-6 they define the inner product of vectors as $x\cdot y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}y_{i}}$

I'm wondering if this is the same as taking $x^Ty$?

Comment: Yes...if by $\;x^ty\;$ you mean product of matrices, and $\;x^t\;$ is a *row* vector (or $\;1\times n\;$ matrix)

Comment: When $x$ is a $n$-dimensional column vector and $y$ is a $n$-dimensional row vector, $x^\top y = \sum_{i=1}^2 x_iy_i$.

Comment: Strictly speaking $x^T y$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix and $x \cdot y$ is a scalar, but the distinction is rather pointless, so everybody considers them the same.

Comment: @DonAntonio so basically it only holds for 1 x n matrix and not for example 2 x n matrix with $n\neq 1$?

Comment: @stenvikteam You asked about the inner product... of **two vectors** . There is no inner product between a $\;2\times n\;$ matrix and a $\;1\times n\;$ vector defined matrix product, which isn't even defined in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for $\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ standard definitions are
$$\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{x}^\intercal\boldsymbol{y} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k y_k.$$

The dot product is defined by the sum, and the second part using transpose is the standard matrix product, which turn out to be the same in this case.

Comment: So basically the requirement is that x and y are bough [1,n] matrices, and it will not hold for any x and y [m,n] matrices where $m,n\neq 1$?

Comment: Yep, [inner products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space), such as the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), act on vectors.